# Unable to follow path using demo data

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the demo and using the sample rosbag as per: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/-/wikis/ROSBAG-Demo

Instead of using the path generated from the rosbag, i plotted my own path on the vector map and saved the waypoints. Next, I loaded the waypoints and activated the 'Mission_PLanning' module..

But when this happens, the vehicle localization is going haywire and I am getting error of 'Cannot get closest waypoints. All closest waypoints are changed to -1...'

The vehicle also overshoots the goal points and continues to follow the rosbag path.

Is there any way I can solve this issue? so that it follows the path I created.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349683/unable-to-follow-path-using-demo-data/) by [titanum456](https://answers.ros.org/users/32191/titanum456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@titanum456 please be aware that the rosbag demo instructions are not using any kind of simulator. They are just replaying what was recorded in the rosbag.

---

Originally posted by [sgermanserrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/41059/sgermanserrano/) with karma: 166 on 2020-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [titanum456](https://answers.ros.org/users/32191/titanum456/) on 2020-04-25**:
that explains the problem. thanks